# PHP does not communicate with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have been messing with this problem for days now. I use a PHP script to enter data into a MySQL database, I get a blank page, or it says it did it, but nothing changes in MySQL. I tried updating from older programs, installing all 32 bit, and installing all 64 bit software. Now that I've updated once and redone everything twice, I am certain I have problem in Windows, but I do not have any idea where to search. I will show you a script I am using, but I know it's a working script as I've used it to test other servers. A major barrier to finding a solution to the problem though, is that every time I find someone with my problem it is largely assumed the script is the problem, I have no error codes, this particular script even says "SUCCESS!"

**System:**
Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 x64
Apache 2.4.7 VC11 x64
PHP 5.5.7 VC11 x64
MySQL Server 5.6.12

**Script:**

```
<?php  // mysql-pdo-test.php
try {
  $user = "[censored]"; $pass = "[censored]";

  echo "-->connect and select database\n";
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=projectedin.local;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

  # activate exception generation
  $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

  echo "<br />-->create table:\n";
  $dbh->exec( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_tab (thing VARCHAR(10))" );

  echo "<br />-->insert into table:\n";
  $dbh->exec( "INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES ('book'),('pencil')" );

  echo "<br />-->select from table:\n";
  $res = $dbh->query( "SELECT thing FROM test_tab" );
  foreach ($res as $row) {
    echo $row['thing'], " ";
  }

  echo "<br />-->drop table:\n";
  $dbh->exec( "DROP TABLE test_tab" );
  echo "<br />SUCCESS!";

  // disconnect
  $dbh = null;
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
  die( "<h4>Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "</h4>" );
}
?>
```

Comment: try `127.0.0.1` as the address for your MySQL server. Windows is kinda funny about local addressing sometimes.

Comment: You are connecting to `projectedin.local`, which implies that MySQL is listening on a TCP socket rather than a named pipe (as it would if you connected to `localhost`).  Can you connect from the MySQL command line to `mysql -h projectedin.local test` ?

Comment: So you're seeing *SUCCESS!* but not *book* and *pencil* from the `foreach` loop? Have you enabled full error reporting (ie `display_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL` in `php.ini`)?

Comment: @Phil I actually do see book and pencil on the generated page if that's what you asking. I also have error_reporting set to E_ALL and display_errors set to on.

Comment: @michaelBerkowski I just tried it in the command prompt but all I get is the second line no matter what I put for the server name, correct or not. (Sorry if there's a step I'm missing. I forgot to mention I'm a noob.)

Comment: @Machavity I just tried 127.0.0.1 in the script, but it still acted the same way. The only reason I changed it is because it's changed in my hosts file.

Comment: @Enki So what's the actual problem here?

Comment: @Phil Sorry I haven't been back for a while. My problem is, no matter what script I use, settings I change, whatever, I can't get anything to show up in MySQL. I just installed Windows Server 2008 hoping it was just a problem with my OS, and redid everything. Now I'm stuck where I began, nothing showing up in MySQL (I'm actually starting to feel cursed). Everything is on my laptop, nothing should be going over my network. Is there anything in the setup of Apache, PHP, or MySQL that could give me a problem if I've done it wrong?

Answer (score -3):

This:

```
$dbh->exec( "INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES ('book'),('pencil')" );
```

is not valid.  Should be:

```
$dbh->exec( "INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES ('book', 'pencil')" );
```

Not sure if that's causing your problem, but it sure isn't helping.

Comment: His table has only 1 column, and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html "INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas"